# pass arguments to gnome-terminal from find -exec command

Tags: linux, shell, find, arguments, gnome-terminal

i a file call "runAllBestScripts.sh". That file has this command:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name 'best*' -a -not -name 'buns*.sh' \) -exec gnome-terminal --tab --title="Build {}" -- bash -c 'echo {} $@; $SHELL' \;
```

i have a file called best.sh in my home directory. find returns the one file. But i want to pass all my arguments to the best.sh file that is going to be ran in the gnome-terminal command.

so when i run

> ./runAllBestScripts.sh -r -k

I want those arguments to be passed to the echo command that will be called in the gnome-terminal. the script file path gets printed from the "{}", but when passing in $@. it does not pass in the arguments to print as well. How would i go about print those arguments without the runAllBestScripts file worrying about them specifically?